# SQL Query Where array of objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a field that contains an array of objects. Here's a sample value of the field

```
[
   {a: "test"},
   {a: "testing"}
]
```

I'm trying to do a query data where the comparison is on the array of object fields that kinda looks like this `SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.a = "test"`. The part that I can't get is on the WHERE condition or is this not possible?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server, etc...)

Comment: @Garett it's postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this

its either of this two

```
   SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.field@>'[{"a":"test"}]'::jsonb
```

or

```
   SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.field::text similar to '%("a": "test")%'
```